# SFML TCP packet receive

Tags: c++, tcp, sfml, packet

I send a packet as client to server and I want to the server sends that packet forward to all client, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int fromID; // receive data from 'fromID'
int Message; // fromID's message

sf::SocketTCP Listener;
if (!Listener.Listen(4567))
    return 1;
// Create a selector for handling several sockets (the listener + the socket associated to each client)
sf::SelectorTCP Selector;

Selector.Add(Listener);

while (true)
{
    unsigned int NbSockets = Selector.Wait();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NbSockets; ++i)
    {
        // Get the current socket
        sf::SocketTCP Socket = Selector.GetSocketReady(i);

        if (Socket == Listener)
        {
        // If the listening socket is ready, it means that we can accept a new connection
            sf::IPAddress Address;
            sf::SocketTCP Client;
            Listener.Accept(Client, &Address);
            cout << "Client connected ! (" << Address << ")" << endl;

            // Add it to the selector
            Selector.Add(Client);
        }
        else
        {
            // Else, it is a client socket so we can read the data he sent
            sf::Packet Packet;
            if (Socket.Receive(Packet) == sf::Socket::Done)
            {

               // Extract the message and display it
                Packet >> Message;
                Packet >> fromID;
                cout << Message << " From: " << fromID << endl;

                //send the message to all clients
                for(unsigned int j = 0; j < NbSockets; ++j)
                {
                    sf::SocketTCP Socket2 = Selector.GetSocketReady(j);

                    sf::Packet SendPacket;
                    SendPacket << Message;
                    if(Socket2.Send(SendPacket) != sf::Socket::Done)
                        cout << "Error sending message to all clients" << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
              // Error : we'd better remove the socket from the selector
                Selector.Remove(Socket);
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Client code:
in Player class I have this function :

```
void Player::ReceiveData()
{
 int mess;
 sf::Packet Packet;
 if(Client.Receive(Packet) == sf::Socket::Done)
 {
    Client.Receive(Packet);
    Packet >> mess;
    cout << mess << endl;
 }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
Player player;
player.Initialize();
player.LoadContent();
player.Connect();
..
..
//GAME LOOP
while(running==true)
{
   sf::Event Event;
   while(..) // EVENT LOOP
   {
   ...
   }
   player.Update(Window);
   player.ReceiveData();
   player.Draw(Window);
}
```

When I run this client code, the program not responding, freezes.
The problem is with that ReceiveDate() function.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the server that's the problem? Run in a debugger and set a breakpoint where you receive a message, and step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: The server runs on other pc, only the client freezes. So..this is a game, the client doesnt freeze until I press some button, but appears only white screen, becoz player.ReceiveData() is running until I get a packet or what ? I dont understand..

Comment: Remember that the sockets are _blocking_ by default. This means that the `Receive` call will _block_ until there is something to receive. So your program will "freeze" when it comes to the `Receive` call.

Comment: So I need to create threads?

Comment: No, see the [`sf::SocketTCP::SetBlocking`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1SocketTCP.php#aa80f7711b15fe33a5c7005acedae43c9) function.

Comment: If I open two client, I get the packet back , but only with sender client..Is problem with "send message to all clients" part. Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

All sockets, even the one created by SFML, are by default blocking. This means that when you try to receive when there is nothing to receive, the call will block, making your application seem "freezed".

You can toggle the blocking status of a SFML socket with the [`sf::SocketTCP::SetBlocking`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1SocketTCP.php#aa80f7711b15fe33a5c7005acedae43c9) function.

---

The problem with sending to all clients failing is because you use `GetSocketReady` to get the clients to send to. That function only returns a socket for clients that are *ready* (i.e. the previous call to `Wait` marked the socket as having input).

You need to refactor the server to keep track of the connected clients in another way. The common way is to reset and recreate the selector every time in the outer loop, and have a separate collection of the connected clients (e.g. a `std::vector`).

Comment: @user1949520 While somewhat related, I think that warrant a separate question. If you post it as a separate question I'll gladly help you best I can with that. :)