# How to fix window freezing issue (not responding) when it comes to receiving message from a client?

Tags: c++, sockets, sfml

I'm using SFML in my C++ code. My problem is similar to this question ([SFML TCP packet receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687046/sfml-tcp-packet-receive)), but since the answers do not satisfy me, I decided to ask a new question.

In my code, server and client will need to exchange confirmation message in order to proceed to the next stage of the program. However, when the server is expecting to receive message from the client, the window freezes by showing "Not Responding", how can I solve this? I have already let setBlocking variable to be false.

My code is as follows:

```
sf::Socket::Status status;
string msg;
if (isServer)
{
    do {
        status = host.receiveMessage(msg);
    } while (status != sf::Socket::Done || msg!= "done1");

    status = host.sendMessage("done1");

}
else
{
    do {
        status = host.sendMessage("done1");
    } while (status != sf::Socket::Done);

    do {
        status = host.receiveMessage(msg);
    } while (status != sf::Socket::Done || msg!= "done1");
}
```

Comment: Sooo.. you have replaced a blocking call with a while loop?

Comment: Oh! I see, so that's because of the while loop. May I know what to do then? I have to wait for the response from client, yet I do not want it to freeze :(

Answer (score 0):

you should create an extra thread to communicate with client.
or use another socket model, when incoming data is available, the window receives a message.

Comment: Do you mind to give me some hints to write the function in the extra thread? I have read the documentation and tried to implement into my code, but it seems I'm still not familiar enough to use the class.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I've tried it myself, but you may find the [source code](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML-Game-Development-Book) of the SFML game dev book useful to look at.

There is a full chapter on networking with sfml (the last one) and you might find all the answers you need there.